# is there any E-Commerce plugin to integrate

Tags: html, web-applications, e-commerce

Is there any web store plugin which I can integrate into my existing web site?

I know that there are a lot of WordPress plugins but as a developer I am making my own apps and I don't want to have their templates because first of all I will charge for those web store services and I can't give them WordPress store..

I was thinking to make a personal e-commerce services but honestly why to spend time and try to "reinvent the wheel".

If anyone knows some plugins which could help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

being a web developer involves a lot of stuff. The **plugin** you are looking for will depend  on how your website has been developed, where is it hosted and **what do you really want to do with it**.

Main questions for a start would be:

- Whats your website address.
- Where is hosted.
- What server will you be using (Shared servers do not allow you to use custom plugins).
- What is your target (This is what you need to concern at the most).

Once you have those questions answered, you can develop anything you want, but before that, if you are looking to create E-Commerce websites for other people or companies, then my advise is for you to start with Shopping Carts.

Shopping Carts have already been tested and might do all your customers need to, unless advanced programming is needed which means that you can code yourself or search on the internet for what you need, as it is most likely to have.

For now, i think you should start with Free Shopping carts like http://opencart.com. All you need to do is create a Database under your server, update the DNS for the URL of the store to point it to your server. After doing this, of course you need to get monthly payments or how you wish, but you need to get the money, so using a [**PayPal**](http://paypal.com) account you can create a **Recurring Payment** Which PayPal will automatically charge your customer according to the settings specified in your Recurring Payment.

I, myself use this as it is the easiest way to do it. Also, there are websites that have option for you to use them as a Service provider/ Partner which means that both you and that company share the profits. It is all up to you.

Hope it helps ;D

**Edit**

I think everyone thought the same easy way ^^,

Soz for reposting.. it had no answers when started :/

Comment: hi, yes I think that shopping cart is what I need. Can I manage html code like you can do it in this service: http://www.shopify.com/tour/website-design

Comment: Hey, have you had a look on the site i linked before? I think i forgot to mention that it its "Free Source" which means that you can edit it everything, including making new AddOns for it.

Comment: The software is coded in PHP and you can modify anything you want, including the user interface for your customer, which will look way better. What you can do to be easier, is to create a .CSS file for the admin side, well just modify the existing one, make sure you save a copy and just upload that .CSS in every single customer interface so that it will display your info rather than the openCart. I have tried shopify before, and let me tell you that it is not as powerful as BigCommerce, and it is not worth for the price you end up paying. Couldn't put all in one.

Comment: nicely explained..my choice is "OpenCart". thank you

Comment: You most welcome. My Pleasure ;D

If you need some help setting up openCart then drop me an e-mail  or contact me using TeamSpeak under http://ptlaggerz.com. Join the server from there.

Comment: can you please write your email..I have some questions

Comment: Not sure if it is allowed, but here it is: afzal@webmasterspt.com

Comment: Easy way would have been contacting me via the link i left before as I am always online. But drop me an e-mail.. i ll see if I can help you

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with what you meant by e-commerce. There is CI framework if you are looking for complete development but with less effort. 
If you are just looking for shopping cart -- check this thread -> [Shopping Cart Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684919/shopping-cart-framework)

If you are looking for commercial use and if to be reliable with less effort you can buy scripts available.

This is one of such product 
http://www.inoutscripts.com/products/inout_shopping_cart/

Comment: thank you for your fast answer...yes I need a plugins to integrate a web store to customers web site..I'll check your links.

Answer (score 0):

A "plugin" might not be enough to run a "store" if you think of all the features a store should have: billing, customer database, product availability, shipping, TAX, etc. – but for a small/simple solution you could look for "carts" like http://www.opencart.com

More pointers here: 
[Which PHP open source shopping cart solutions have features that benefit me as the web developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69715/which-php-open-source-shopping-cart-solutions-have-features-that-benefit-me-as-t)

(is this a possible duplicate?)